# Customer community vs partner community

Tags: community

Can anyone tell me what are the 5 types of community in salesforce...
Purpose of those type of community and how they differ...
Pros and cons of each type of community

Thanks in advance

Karthick

Answer (score 2):

You can find a general overview on:
http://www.salesforce.com/communities/overview/

If you need more details, please rephrase your question.

Comment: can you give me the answer for my question as i mentioned above

Comment: Again, at the bottom of that page there is a decent comparison between the communities. Not sure what else you are looking for.